# Optimize ApiResource

Tags: laravel, api, resources, many-to-many, eager-loading

I'm having some problems when returning ApiResources because I can't figure out how to avoid overloading relationships.

In my UserResource, for example, I have:

```php
<?php

return [
    'id' => $this->id,
    'name' => $this->name,
    'email' => $this->email,
    'role_id' => $this->role_id,
    'role' => new RoleResource($this->whenLoaded('role')),
    'group_ids' => $this->groups->pluck('id')->toArray(), // here are the problems
    'groups' => GroupResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('groups')),
];
```

When loading single relationship id, all is ok, because `$this->role_id` is a property that is already in the Model. When using `$this->whenLoaded('role')` It will load the relationship conditionally, that's great!

**The Problem**: When loading many-to-many relationships, I can't set this 'conditional' eager load.

When I place:

`'groups' => GroupResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('groups'))`

It will load the ManyToMany Relation conditionally, cool!

**BUT** I would like to have array of ids with:

`'group_ids' => $this->groups->pluck('id')->toArray()`

However, this **will execute the relation load ALWAYS**

Comment: You could replace `$this->groups->pluck("id")->toArray();` with the `DB::table()` equivalent, like `DB::table("groups")->where({logic applied by $this->groups})->pluck("id")->toArray();`, which would avoid using (loading) the `groups` relationship, but still return associated `group_ids`. You might even be able to use `$this->group` when `$this->whenLoaded("groups")`, and `DB::table()` otherwise

Comment: You will need this `group_ids` all the time or just if the relation is loaded ?

Comment: Correct, I would like to have it only when the relation is loaded, some very similar to `$this->whenLoaded()` that returns a `MissingValue` when the relation is not loaded.